# Here is C code for the Vernam Cipher, how to take digits as an input message instead of strings?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

char arr[26][26];
char message[22], key[22], emessage[22], retMessage[22];
int findRow(char);
int findColumn(char);
int findDecRow(char, int);

int main() {
    int i = 0, j, k, r, c;
    clrscr();
    k = 47;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        k++;
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = k++;
            if (k == 59) 
                k = 48;
        }
    }
    printf("\nEnter message\n");
    gets(message);
    printf("\nEnter the key\n");
    gets(key);
    // Encryption 
    for (i = 0; key[i] != NULL; i++) {
        c = findRow(key[i]);
        r = findColumn(message[i]);
        emessage[i] = arr[r][c];
    }
    emessage[i] = '\0';
    printf("\n Encrypted message is:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; emessage[i] != NULL; i++) 
        printf("%c", emessage[i]);
    //decryption 
    for (i = 0; key[i] != NULL; i++) {
        c = findColumn(key[i]);
        r = findDecRow(emessage[i], c);
        retMessage[i] = arr[r][0];
    }
    retMessage[i] = '\0';
    printf("\n\nMessage Retrieved is:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; retMessage[i] != NULL; i++) 
      printf("%c", retMessage[i]);
    getch();
    return (0);
}

int findRow(char c) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (arr[0][i] == c) 
           return (i);
    }
}

int findColumn(char c) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (arr[i][0] == c) 
           return (i);
    }
}

int findDecRow(char c, int j) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == c) 
           return (i);
    }
}
```

this is a Vernam Cipher program used to encrypt and decrypt the data using a key. 
problem is that, this program cannot take digits as input. how to edit it so that we can take digits as input and encrypt it? no need to change for key, only `message` needs to be changed to digits.
And also the output, ie `Message Retrieved` must be in digits too, as we are decrypting the data.

Comment: Try using `scanf` instead of `gets`?

Comment: Yeah. `gets` is insecure. At the very least, use `fgets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Isn't it Vigenère (not Vernam)?

If it's Vigenère you just have to define properly what is your input alphabet. Actually your code has input alphabet lowercased letters (a-z), so that the Vigenère code is something like:

```
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
aabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza
ccdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab
...
```

Just add your digits anywhere you want in the code:

```
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
aabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
bbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789a
ccdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ab
...
```

--- EDIT ---

You may need to add another small layer that lets you define your input alphabet. So define an array containing all the considered letter in a given order (choose one) say:

```
Alphabet[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Now imagine you have a function that given a letter will give you its rank in the alphabet : say `rank(l)`, for example `rank('b')=11`.

Now compute (there is no need for such structure but let's do it like you did) your permutations:

```
Perms[][]
   00 01 02 03 04 05 .... 35
00 00 01 02 03 04 05 .... 35
01 01 02 03 04 05 .... 35 00
02 02 03 04 05 .... 35 00 01
...
```

Now for a given key letter `k` and a message letter `l` you can compute the enciphered letter `e` as:

```
e = Alphabet[Perms[rank(l)][rank[k]]
```

Comment: It is Vernam Cipher not Vigenère cipher !

Comment: Isn't it the same? https://www.britannica.com/topic/Vernam-Vigenere-cipher

Comment: Yeah..thanks both are same..but can you help me where in the code I need to modify for digits?

Comment: Jean..can you help me out? Please

Comment: @JL2210 Well we can say that the algorithm is the same in both, but that usages and inputs differ (Vernam is OTP so unbreakable, Vigenère is short key then breakable).

Comment: thank you @JL2210 it worked! but after decryption, some extra characters are being printed at last.. example, my message: 571635 key: BYUg872e78 encrypted: G`Vm;< Decrypt: 571635a. that 'a' at last is an extra character.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but do you go beyond the bonds of an array in any of this code?